# Accessing Model Through Custom Class

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to access a model through a class.
I'm trying to get this done on a Laravel 5.5 installation.
The folder structure is the default except for I have a folder in App/Libraries that holds my custom classes.

My issue is I get the below error when I'm trying to access a model through my class. Probably a namespace issue, but I just can't seem to find it. It's looking at the wrong place.

The error is

> Class 'App\Libraries\App\AccountsModel' not found

Below is my code.

app/Libraries/Account.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;
use App\AccountsModel;
class Account {



public $accountNum;
    public $accountDescription;
    public $isMainAccount;
    public $parentAccount;
    public $createTime;
    public $updatedTime;

    public function getInfo($accountNum)
    {
        $account = App\AccountsModel::where('accountNumber', $accountNum)->take(1)->get(); //Error coming up due to this line
        //return $account;
        //return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

app\AccountsModel.php

```
<?php
namespace App\AccountsModel; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccountsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'accounts';

}
```

app/Http/Controllers/AccountsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Libraries\Account;

class AccountsController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $account = new Account;
        var_dump($account->getInfo("1-1000"));
    }
}
```

I'm autoloading the model on composer.json as below.
Any input on the below is also appreciated.
I tried echoing the class name on a construct in the model, with no echo so I'm guessing I'm autoloading this incorrectly too.

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "AccountsModel\\" : "app/AccountsModel.php"
        }
    },
```

Ultimately I'm trying to access the model through my custom Account class when I get the error.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try changing `namespace App\Libraries;` to `namespace App;
`

Comment: Did it. Now I get "Class 'App\Libraries\Account' not found". But the class names Account.php is there in the mentioned directory. Any idea?

Comment: remove namespace App\AccountsModel; and use  namespace App;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `AccountsModel` already include in `use` section. So, you can just use `AccountsModel` instead of `App\AccountsModel`. See the updated code below

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;
use App\AccountsModel;
class Account {



public $accountNum;
    public $accountDescription;
    public $isMainAccount;
    public $parentAccount;
    public $createTime;
    public $updatedTime;

    public function getInfo($accountNum)
    {
        $account = AccountsModel::where('accountNumber', $accountNum)->take(1)->get(); // this line updated
    }
}
?>
```

Update your model to this. Just `namespace App;`

```
<?php
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccountsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'accounts';

}
```

Also, this is not needed in composer.json since the `AccountModel` is part of `App`.

```
"AccountsModel\\" : "app/AccountsModel.php"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `app/AccountsModel.php` file the namespace should be `App`

```
namespace App;
```

and there's no need of the following entry in `composer.json` file

```
"AccountsModel\\" : "app/AccountsModel.php"
```